# IndexOutOfBoundsException on ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

For some reason, this method is returning `viewType = 2` at the first location in my ArrayList. Is that because 0 divided by 5 does not produce a remainder? If I set `&& position != 0` instead of 1 I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int viewType = 1;
        // Ads appear where the position in the list divided by 5 does not produce a remainder, i.e. 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, etc.
        if ((position % 5 == 0) && position != 1) viewType = 2;
        return viewType;
}
```

Ideally I'd have my ad placement (viewType = 2) appear every 25 positions, excluding the very first one. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

```
public class MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter extends LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter {

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_AD = 2;

    private final Context context;
    private final List<Feed> feedItems;
    private final ImageLoader feedItemImageLoader;
    private FeedItemClickListener feedItemClickListener;

    private boolean isLongPressed = false;
    public MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Feed> feedItems, ImageLoader feedItemImageLoader, List<Feed> adItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
        this.feedItemImageLoader = feedItemImageLoader;
        if (!adItems.isEmpty()) { feedItems.addAll(adItems); }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED:
                return new MarketFeedViewHolder(new FeedItemView(context));
            case VIEW_TYPE_AD:
                return new AdViewHolder(new MarketFeedAdItemView(context));
        }
        return super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
    }

    // Differentiate between feedItem views and nativeAds
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            int viewType = 1;
            // Ads appear where the position in the list divided by 5 does not produce a remainder, i.e. 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, etc.
            if ((position % 5 == 0)) viewType = 2;
            return viewType;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED) {
            bindMarketFeedItemView((MarketFeedViewHolder) viewHolder, position);
        }  else {
            bindAdItemView((AdViewHolder) viewHolder);
        }
    }

    // For Ad Objects
    private void bindAdItemView(AdViewHolder viewHolder) {

        showNativeAd(viewHolder);

    }

    private void bindMarketFeedItemView(MarketFeedViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        final FeedItemView feedItemView = viewHolder.feedItemView;
        final Feed feedDesign = feedItems.get(position);

        // TODO we can probably conditionally show or hide these based on the type of feed item, same as in FeedActivitySingle
        feedItemView.showOrHideEditButton(false);
        feedItemView.showOrHideBuyButton(true);
        feedItemView.showOrHideFlipButton(feedDesign.getDesign().getCompressedBackImage() != null);
        feedItemView.showOrHidePriceText(true);

        // Set the results into TextViews
        feedItemView.setProductPriceText(String.valueOf(feedDesign.getDesign().getPrice()));
        feedItemView.setDownloadsText(String.valueOf(feedDesign.getDesign().getDownloadCount()));
        feedItemView.setLikesText(String.valueOf(feedDesign.getDesign().getLikesCount()));
        feedItemView.setUsernameText(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getUsername());
        feedItemView.setTimestampText(feedDesign.getTimestampText());
        feedItemView.getSaveImage().setImageResource(feedDesign.isInPersonalGallery() ? R.drawable.ic_action_saved : R.drawable.ic_not_saved);
        feedItemView.getLikeImage().setImageResource(feedDesign.isLiked() ? R.drawable.ic_action_like_feed_full : R.drawable.ic_action_like_feed);

        feedItemView.getTrashImage().setVisibility(ParseHelper.isCurrentUser(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getObjectId()) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        feedItemView.getFeedSocialShareImage().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        switch(feedDesign.getDisplayedSide()) {
            case FRONT:
                feedItemImageLoader.DisplayImage(feedDesign.getDesign().getCompressedImage().getUrl(), feedItemView.getImage(), feedItemView.getProgressBar());
                break;
            case BACK:
                feedItemImageLoader.DisplayImage(feedDesign.getDesign().getCompressedBackImage().getUrl(), feedItemView.getImage(), feedItemView.getProgressBar());
                break;
        }

        if(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getProfilePicture() != null) {
            feedItemImageLoader.DisplayImage(feedDesign.getDesign().getAuthor().getProfilePicture().getUrl(), feedItemView.getProfilePicture(), null); // TODO should this use profilePictureFileCache?
        } else {
            viewHolder.feedItemView.getProfilePicture().setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_anonymous);
        }

        SetCommentViews(feedItemView, feedDesign.getComments());
        SetClickListeners(feedItemView, feedDesign, position);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getContentDataSize() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getViewType(int position) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED;
    }

    class MarketFeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        FeedItemView feedItemView;

        public MarketFeedViewHolder(FeedItemView view) {
            super(view);
            this.feedItemView = view;
        }
    }

    class AdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        MarketFeedAdItemView adItemView;

        public AdViewHolder(MarketFeedAdItemView view) {
            super(view);
            this.adItemView = view;
        }

    }

    private NativeAd nativeAd;
    private AdChoicesView adChoicesView;

    private void showNativeAd(AdViewHolder viewHolder){
        AdSettings.addTestDevice("STRING");
        nativeAd = new NativeAd(context, "STRING");
        nativeAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {

                final MarketFeedAdItemView adItemView = viewHolder.adItemView;

                // Setting the Text
                adItemView.nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
                adItemView.nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());
                adItemView.nativeAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle());
                adItemView.nativeAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());

                // Downloading and setting the ad icon
                NativeAd.Image adIcon = nativeAd.getAdIcon();
                NativeAd.downloadAndDisplayImage(adIcon, adItemView.nativeAdIcon);

                // Download and setting the cover image
                /*NativeAd.Image adCoverImage = nativeAd.getAdCoverImage();*/
                adItemView.nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

                // Add adChoices icon
                if (adChoicesView == null) {
                    adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(context, nativeAd, true);
                    adItemView.addView(adChoicesView, 0);
                }

                nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(adItemView);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

            }
        });

        nativeAd.loadAd();
    }
}
```

**Error Output**

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
         at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
         at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
         at com.elgami.market.MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.bindMarketFeedItemView(MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.java:94)
         at com.elgami.market.MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.java:79)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5768)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5801)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5037)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3260)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3069)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3518)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
         at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:598)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
        at android.view.Choreographe
```

**LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter:**

```
public abstract class LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final int ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 72398; // obscure number
    private boolean mContainsLoadingRow;

    protected abstract int getContentDataSize();

    protected abstract int getViewType(int position);

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING:
                return new LoadingViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.loading_row, parent, false));
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("viewType is not ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING. You must handle all other values of viewType (defined by getViewType) before calling super.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // empty
    }

    @Override
    public final int getItemCount() {
        return mContainsLoadingRow ? (getContentDataSize() + 1) : getContentDataSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == getContentDataSize()) ? ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : getViewType(position);
    }

    /**
     * Sets a boolean which is used by getItemCount and in turn getItemViewType to determine which view type the row should be (loading view vs. other view).
     * Should only be called when there is more results to load in an upcoming api request (determined by calling fragment).
     */
    public void toggleLoadingRowOn() {
        mContainsLoadingRow = true;
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if a loading row exists by checking an instance boolean and removes the row / clears the boolean.
     * This helps to 'replace' a loading row with a different row.
     */
    public void toggleLoadingRowOff() {
        if (mContainsLoadingRow) {
            mContainsLoadingRow = false;

            // removes the loading row explicitly instead of allowing it to be 'pushed' down when new user suggestion rows are added.
            // this is only required to maintain consistency with the rest of the app.
            int position = getContentDataSize();
            if (position >= 0) {
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
        }
    }

    protected class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public LoadingViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }
}
```

**LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter:**

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private static final int VISIBLE_THRESHOLD = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    public abstract void onLoadMore();

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        int totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        int visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();

        int lastItemVisible = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

        // once the last visible item is within VISIBLE_THRESHOLD from the bottom, we want to load more
        if ((totalItemCount - lastItemVisible) <= VISIBLE_THRESHOLD) {
            onLoadMore();
        }
    }
}
```

**NEW STACKTRACE**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
   at com.elgami.market.MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.bindMarketFeedItemView(MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.java:93)
   at com.elgami.market.MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.java:78)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5768)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5801)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5037)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3260)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3069)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3518)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:598)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreograph
```

Comment: Place the whole Adapter class code.

Comment: Okay I pasted it all in.

Comment: I added the error as well.

Comment: The error is coming in `onBindViewHolder` not in `getItemViewType()`

Comment: If I set ``if (position != 1 && position % 5 == 0)`` everything is fine but no other combination works.

Comment: What does `getViewTypeMethod()` do, check somewhere the list is empty.

Comment: your error is due to empty **feedItems**. Please try to log it

Comment: I'm curious though why the condition ``(position != 1 && position % 5 == 0)`` doesn't produce empty feedItems. Must be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to do this:

```
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED = 0;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_AD = 1;

...

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int viewType = VIEW_TYPE_MARKET_FEED;
    if (position % 6 == 5) {
        viewType = VIEW_TYPE_AD;
    }
    return viewType;
}
```

Because you cannot have a view type of 2 because: "[Integers must be in the range 0 to getViewTypeCount() - 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int))".

Also, in the method `public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)`, change the line:

```
bindMarketFeedItemView((MarketFeedViewHolder) viewHolder, position);
```

with:

```
bindMarketFeedItemView((MarketFeedViewHolder) viewHolder, position - position / 6);
```

In order to remove add items you have inserted.

Comment: Should I change the viewTypes to 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2?

Comment: Okay either way I still get ``java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0``

Comment: Actually the crash appears in the line 94 which should be: "final Feed feedDesign = feedItems.get(position);". Your "feedItems" list seems to be empty.

Comment: Yeah I see that and I've been trying to figure out why forever.

Comment: It depends on what you provide in the constructor for parameters "feedItems" and "adItems".

Comment: ``List<Feed> adItems = new ArrayList<>();``
``marketFeedRecyclerAdapter = new MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter(this, feedItems, new ImageLoader(new FeedItemFileCache(this)), adItems);``

Comment: I think there is a problem with your class "LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter". What does it provide for "getCount()"? It seems to be something greater than what you return in your "getContentDataSize()" method.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by what does it provide for getCount()? I don't even have that method.

Comment: "LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter" is not a class provided by Android SDK. Is it yours? An adapter has a method "getCount()" which returns the number of items in the adapter. I don't see it, instead I see a custom method "getContentDataSize()".

Comment: Yeah it's my own method.

Comment: I have update my answer. I think I have found your problem.

Comment: Only thing is that  ``&& position > 0`` still produces the exception. Removing that fixes the problem, but has the unwanted side effect of that view appearing in the first slot.

Comment: :) It's strange, it shouldn't crashed. If you remove `&& position > 0`, check if no item is missing because `position - position / 6` expects that there is no ad in first position.

Comment: What does the ``position - position / 6`` actually mean? I'm a little lost there. Actually the first feedItem is missing and it is replaced by an adItem.

Comment: You repeatedly have 5 "market feed", then an ad. So ads are in positions 5, 11, 17, ... (0 1 2 3 4 **5** 6 7 8 9 10 **11** 12 ...). `position - position / 6` remove ad items that are before a "market feed" item when computing its index. For instance, for an item at index 3 (which corresponds to the 4th "market feed", this formula returns "3" (3 - 0 = 3). For an item at index 12 (which corresponds to the 11th "market feed", this formula returns "10" (12 - 2 = 10), which is the right index when the 2 ads before are removed.

Comment: I see. Then why is the first market feed gobbled up by an ad, i.e. 0 has an ad and the feedItem is gone?

Comment: position 0 % 5 == 0, which would mean an ad is placed at 0, except for position > 0 should exclude that possibility. Regardless, an ad appears at 0.

Comment: Because you have removed `&& position > 0`.

Comment: Yes but removing that causes an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I posted it. I think there are actually three view types in total, including the ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING from the LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter, and that could be causing the problem, by creating extra spaces that aren't accounted for by ``position - position / 6``.

Comment: Ok thanks. It seems to be the same stack trace. Yes I think this is due to your third view type. Why ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING has the value `72398`? Remember, "Integers must be in the range 0 to getViewTypeCount() - 1". I think to fix your problem you have to check if mContainsLoadingRow is equal to true, if so, remove 1 to the position. Also, your "getItemViewType" method in MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter overrides the super ones, so it seems that you never have the type `ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING`.

Comment: Yes I changed getItemViewType in MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter to getViewType and it complains ``java.lang.ClassCastException: com.elgami.utility.LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter$LoadingViewHolder cannot be cast to com.elgami.market.MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter$AdViewHolder at com.elgami.market.MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter.java:80)`` which means I am getting closer. The number 72398 is some obscure number the user would never reach. When the user reaches the bottom I give ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING that number and check it to load more rows.

Comment: Do you mean here ``@Override
    public final int getItemCount() {
        return mContainsLoadingRow ? (getContentDataSize() + 1) : getContentDataSize();
    }``?

Comment: No. This: `@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) { return (position == getContentDataSize()) ? ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : getViewType(position); }`. And ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING cannot have this value `72398`. According to documentation, it should be between 0 and 2 included.

Comment: I took out the view bindings entirely to see what was going on without the data. It appears that under ``position % 5 == 0`` you get the following pattern, where A is an ad and D is data: A, D, D, D, D, A, D, D, D, D, A, etc., so 1 ad, 4 data, etc.; but with ``position % 5 == 0 && position > 0`` you get: D, D, D, D, D, A, D, D, D, D, A. (5 data, 1 ad, 4 data, 1 ad, 4 data, 1 ad, 4 data, 1 ad, etc.

Comment: Your pattern above shows 5 Ds and one A. I'm only ever getting 4 at a time, and most 5 only once when ``position > 0``.

Comment: Oh yes sorry! If you need 5D, 1A, 5D, 1A, etc., so I think you just need `position % 6 == 5`

Comment: I understand but the point I'm trying to make is that either the equation, or something else entirely might be wrong. The first feedItem is being overwritten by the first ad, so we are one item short. ``&& position > 0`` destroys the activity and causes an exception, so I am forced to stay with only ``position % 5 == 0``.

Comment: Yes, because as I told you, in your method: `@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) { int viewType = 1; // Ads appear where the position in the list divided by 5 does not produce a remainder, i.e. 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, etc. if ((position % 5 == 0)) viewType = 2; return viewType; }`, you don't call super and so at position 0 you never get `ROW_VIEW_TYPE_LOADING`.

Comment: Ok, just rename `getItemViewType ` with `getViewType` in `MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter`. This should work...

Comment: Okay sorry for all that. I changed getItemViewTpye in MarketFeedRecyclerAdapter to getViewType as you suggested, but made sure to leave getItemViewType in onBindViewHolder the way it was, so that it refers to LoadingRowRecyclerAdapter.